# Google Analytics API Multiple account authorization

Tags: google-analytics, authorization, google-analytics-api

Is it possible to make multiple account authorization for Google Analytics API ? I'm creating a service on top of Google Analytics API. You can login with your account and get data you need. There are users which have multiple accounts for analytics. For example 2.

How can I authorize both accounts in Google in the same time and retreive data from both Google accounts ?

By Accounts - I mean different email's : example1@gmail.com, example2@gmail.com.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't, you have to perform 2 different oAuth flows, get 2 tokens and perform 2 separate queries for each account.

Comment: So I actually can authorize with oAuth 2 users (one after another), get 2 tokens and perform queries according GA accounts, can I ?

Comment: Yes you can do that, but these are 2 separate queries, not at the same time. Why wouldn't you be able to do that?